# How to add horizontal bar in table row whose width depends on the value passed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graph, tablerow

I am implementing vote application in which i need to show horizontal bar in table row whose width is depended on particular value. This horizontal bar will act as a indicator to show percentage of vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be like this.....

Use two `UILabels`..... with different color..... combined length of this label would be 100px and we will vary individual's length based on the percentage......

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use progress bar in the 'cell. backgroundView'. 
or you can have imageView and overriding its draw rect method to draw the percentage of votes